# What is the encrypted text shown in address bar?

Tags: security, encryption, web

first I don't know whether it is a right place to ask this Question or not. When we open some specific site or submit some form or login to some site, then in the address bar some encrypted text are appended as a query string but I don't have any idea whether it is a session id or some thing else.
And if it is a session id then is it a good approach to disclose the session id.

Like.   **https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=q1HiWI2kLO3s8Ae3raXwCQ**

https://my.naukri.com/Inbox/viewRecruiterMails?id=d786bc1c09837cc9ca692d042c01186294584fccc83209d4fe409a9be01b6ec61edd7a843282321a

The string ei= in first example and id= in second one

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is just *encoded* binary values (byte values). The first instance seems to be using base 64 for the encoding (probably the URL-safe variant of it) and the second one uses hexadecimal encoding of the bytes.

What the meaning is of the data (possibly after decoding) depends on the protocol defined for the site. There aren't any specific rules. ID's generally contain about 128 bits of randomness though.